# Share link is broken in articles

Tags: bug, status-completed, collectives, articles

Clicking on the share link in an article creates a link that leads to page 404.

For example, in the article https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud/articles/68104924/listen-for-authentication-state-in-android when I copy the share link and then paste it in URL bar I get 404.

The copied link is:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud/collectives/google-cloud/articles/68104924/listen-for-authentication-state-in-android
```

Comment: Also, why is the pop-over missing the "Share to social media" buttons? I mean I never used that feature myself but I imagine there are users who do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out, the bug has been fixed now.